# Generics and factory method

Tags: java, generics, factory

I have two simple classes that extends an interface:

```
public interface Product 
{

}

public class ProductA implements Product
{

}

public class ProductB implements Product
{

}
```

I have two 'services' classes: ServiceA and ServiceB. Each one works with one of the Product classes defined before. Both implements Service interface.

```
public interface Service<T extends Product>
{
   public void print (T product); 
}

public class ServiceA implements Service<ProductA>
{
  public void print (ProductA product)
  {
      System.out.println("Product A");
  } 
}


public class ServiceB implements Service<ProductB>
{
  public void print (ProductB product)
  {
      System.out.println("Product B");
  }

}
```

I would like to developed a factory to instantiate my services:

[BEFORE I FOUND SOLUTION]

```
public class FactoryService
{
   public static Service<? extends Product> getService (String serviceType)
   {
      Service<? extends Product> s = null;
    
      if ("1".equals(serviceType))              
          s =  new ServiceA();
      else if ("2".equals(serviceType))     
          s = new ServiceB();           
    
      return s;
  }
}
```

[SOLUTION]

```
public static <T> T getService (Type targetType)
{
    T service = null;
    
    if (!targetType.getClass().isInstance(Product.class))
        throw new RuntimeException();
        
    if (ProductA.class.getTypeName().equals(targetType.getTypeName()))
        service = (T) new ServiceA();
    else if (ProductB.class.getTypeName().equals(targetType.getTypeName()))
        service = (T) new ServiceB();
    
    return service;     
}
```

When I tried to use my factory I get compile errors:

[BEFORE I FOUND SOLUTION]

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{       
    Product pA = new ProductA();
    Product pB = new ProductB();
    Service<? extends Product> service = FactoryService.getService("1");
    service.print(pA);                      
}
```

[SOLUTION]

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{       
    Product pA = new ProductA();
    Product pB = new ProductB();

    Service<Product> service = FactoryService.getService(pA.getClass());
    service.print(pA);
    
    service = FactoryService.getService(pB.getClass());
    service.print(pB);
    
// No compilation errors
    
}
```

The error says:

The method print(capture#5-of ? extends Product) in the type Service<capture#5-of ? extends Product> is not applicable for the arguments (Product).

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: That's because a `Service<? extends Product>` is not a `Service<ProductA>`, so the compiler cannot check if it's correct to call it with a `ProductA` object. Note that `?` does not mean you can call it with any `Product`. The `? extends Product` means: "some unknown type that extends `Product`". Since the exact type is unknown, you can't use it. The same reason as why you cannot add anything to a `List<? extends Whatever>` in Java.

Comment: But then how could I develop a FactoryService class? I want to get the proper service and invoke the print method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to use generics in declaring a type, you shouldn't use `<? extends Type>` as Jesper pointed out. Instead you should use `<Type>`. In your case, replace `Service<? extends Product>` with `Service<Product>`.
Now you'll get another error:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from ServiceA to Service<Product>

The solution I suggest is instead of defining `ServiceA` and `ServiceB`, to just use the `Service#print` method and check the generic type, then do what is necessary. The `FactoryService#getService` method is not needed in this case.

Spoiler for my solution (try without it first):

> `public class Service<T extends Product> {`
>      `public void print(T product) {`
>          `if (product instanceof ProductA) {`
>              `System.out.println("Product A");`
>          `} else if (product instanceof ProductB) {`
>              `System.out.println("Product B");`
>          `}`
>      `}`
>  `}`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found a solution although I'm not sure if it is the best solution. I'm going to redit my question with the solution.

Comment: Sure! My solution was just in case you didn't find anything else. Well done!